# Java Constructor Inheritance. Constructor is undefined

Tags: java

I am working on a project where I needed to create a class that extends another class and listed below is my constructor for said class. I am getting an error which is "The constructor Monkey(String, String, String, String, String, String, String, String, String, String, String, boolean, String) is undefined" when trying to create a method in my primary method class.

My monkey constructor in my monkey class

```
public Monkey(String name, String gender, String age, String weight, String tailLength, String height, String bodyLength, String species, String acquisitionDate, String aquisitionCountry, boolean reserved, String inServiceCountry) {
        setName(name);
    setGender(gender);
    setAge(age);
    setWeight(weight);
    setTailLength(tailLength);
    setHeight(height);
    setBodyLength(bodyLength);
    setSpecies(species);
    setAcquisitionDate(acquisitionDate);
    setAcquisitionLocation(acquisitionCountry);
    setTrainingStatus(trainingStatus);
    setReserved(reserved);
    setInServiceCountry(inServiceCountry);
```

The method in my primary class

```
public static void initializeMonkeyList() {
        Monkey monkey1 = new Monkey("Steve", "male", "24", "15.4", "12", "20", "16", "capuchin", "04-26-1999", "United States", "intake", false, "United States");
        monkeyList.add(monkey1);
}
```

Comment: Sorry, the format came out weird in the constructor for my monkey class setName isn't tabbed over like in my post.

Comment: You are missing `String trainingStatus` between these two parameters: `String aquisitionCountry, boolean reserved`

Comment: You should really use a builder instead, though.

Comment: @Vertuzi Please [edit] your question to include the full complete error message you get.

Comment: Full error is "The constructor Monkey(String, String, String, String, String, String, String, String, String, String, String, boolean, String) is undefined

Comment: Thank you it didn't completely solve it for some reason but I added traingStatus and added a c into acquisitionCountry so it was spelled right.

Comment: @Vertuzi You are trying to call a constructor with 11 strings, 1 boolean and 1 string parameters. However, your constructor in your class has only 10 strings, 1 boolean and 1 string parameters. That doesn't match.

Comment: @Vertuzi Please [edit] your question to include the full complete error message, do not add it as a comment.

Comment: If you would use dedicated DomainValues, your constructor arguments would tell you which value is expected in which position instead of counting the string arguments and running into silly stackoverflow questions.

Comment: And setters are used for setting the values after they got initialized in the constructor. Use regular value initialization e.g. `this.gender = gender` in the constructor.

Answer (score 4):

You have some issues in your code:

- There is a typo in “acquisitionCountry” and it should be “acquisitionLocation”. The corrected line should be setAcquisitionLocation(acquisitionLocation);
- The constructor is missing the “trainingStatus” parameter.
- The “intake” value is in the wrong place when calling the constructor.

Here’s the corrected version:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

class Scratch {
    static List<Monkey> monkeyList = new ArrayList<>();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        initializeMonkeyList();
        System.out.println(monkeyList);
    }

    public static void initializeMonkeyList() {
        Monkey monkey1 = new Monkey("Steve", "male", "24", "15.4", "12", "20", "16", "capuchin", "04-26-1999", "United States",  false, "United States", "intake");
        monkeyList.add(monkey1);
    }


    public static class Monkey {

        String name,  gender,  age,  weight,  tailLength,  height,  bodyLength,  species,  acquisitionDate, acquisitionCountry, inServiceCountry, trainingStatus;
        boolean reserved;

        public Monkey(String name, String gender, String age, String weight, String tailLength, String height, String bodyLength, String species, String acquisitionDate, String acquisitionCountry, boolean reserved, String inServiceCountry, String trainingStatus) {
            setName(name);
            setGender(gender);
            setAge(age);
            setWeight(weight);
            setTailLength(tailLength);
            setHeight(height);
            setBodyLength(bodyLength);
            setSpecies(species);
            setAcquisitionDate(acquisitionDate);
            setAcquisitionCountry(acquisitionCountry);
            setTrainingStatus(trainingStatus);
            setReserved(reserved);
            setInServiceCountry(inServiceCountry);
        }


        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Monkey{" +
                    "name='" + name + '\'' +
                    ", gender='" + gender + '\'' +
                    ", age='" + age + '\'' +
                    ", weight='" + weight + '\'' +
                    ", tailLength='" + tailLength + '\'' +
                    ", height='" + height + '\'' +
                    ", bodyLength='" + bodyLength + '\'' +
                    ", species='" + species + '\'' +
                    ", acquisitionDate='" + acquisitionDate + '\'' +
                    ", acquisitionCountry='" + acquisitionCountry + '\'' +
                    ", inServiceCountry='" + inServiceCountry + '\'' +
                    ", trainingStatus='" + trainingStatus + '\'' +
                    ", reserved=" + reserved +
                    '}';
        }

        public void setTrainingStatus(String trainingStatus) {
            this.trainingStatus = trainingStatus;
        }

        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        public void setGender(String gender) {
            this.gender = gender;
        }

        public void setAge(String age) {
            this.age = age;
        }

        public void setWeight(String weight) {
            this.weight = weight;
        }

        public void setTailLength(String tailLength) {
            this.tailLength = tailLength;
        }

        public void setHeight(String height) {
            this.height = height;
        }

        public void setBodyLength(String bodyLength) {
            this.bodyLength = bodyLength;
        }

        public void setSpecies(String species) {
            this.species = species;
        }

        public void setAcquisitionDate(String acquisitionDate) {
            this.acquisitionDate = acquisitionDate;
        }

        public void setAcquisitionCountry(String acquisitionCountry) {
            this.acquisitionCountry = acquisitionCountry;
        }

        public void setInServiceCountry(String inServiceCountry) {
            this.inServiceCountry = inServiceCountry;
        }

        public void setReserved(boolean reserved) {
            this.reserved = reserved;
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
[Monkey{name='Steve', gender='male', age='24', weight='15.4', tailLength='12', height='20', bodyLength='16', species='capuchin', acquisitionDate='04-26-1999', acquisitionCountry='United States', inServiceCountry='United States', trainingStatus='intake', reserved=false}]
```

It is not considered good practice to have a large number of arguments. As suggested by others, you could implement the builder pattern.

Here is an example implementation using the builder pattern:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

class Scratch {
    static List<Monkey> monkeyList = new ArrayList<>();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        initializeMonkeyList();
        System.out.println(monkeyList);
    }

    public static void initializeMonkeyList() {
        Monkey monkey1 = new Monkey.Builder()
                .name("Steve")
                .gender("male")
                .age("24")
                .weight("15.4")
                .tailLength("12")
                .height("20")
                .bodyLength("16")
                .species("capuchin")
                .acquisitionDate("04-26-1999")
                .acquisitionCountry("United States")
                .reserved(false)
                .inServiceCountry("United States")
                .trainingStatus("intake")
                .build();
        monkeyList.add(monkey1);
    }

    public static class Monkey {
        private String name, gender, age, weight, tailLength, height, bodyLength, species, acquisitionDate, acquisitionCountry, inServiceCountry, trainingStatus;
        private boolean reserved;

        private Monkey(Builder builder) {
            this.name = builder.name;
            this.gender = builder.gender;
            this.age = builder.age;
            this.weight = builder.weight;
            this.tailLength = builder.tailLength;
            this.height = builder.height;
            this.bodyLength = builder.bodyLength;
            this.species = builder.species;
            this.acquisitionDate = builder.acquisitionDate;
            this.acquisitionCountry = builder.acquisitionCountry;
            this.inServiceCountry = builder.inServiceCountry;
            this.trainingStatus = builder.trainingStatus;
            this.reserved = builder.reserved;
        }

        public static class Builder {
            private String name, gender, age, weight, tailLength, height, bodyLength, species, acquisitionDate, acquisitionCountry, inServiceCountry, trainingStatus;
            private boolean reserved;

            public Builder name(String name) {
                this.name = name;
                return this;
            }

            public Builder gender(String gender) {
                this.gender = gender;
                return this;
            }

            public Builder age(String age) {
                this.age = age;
                return this;
            }

            public Builder weight(String weight) {
                this.weight = weight;
                return this;
            }

            public Builder tailLength(String tailLength) {
                this.tailLength = tailLength;
                return this;
            }

            public Builder height(String height) {
                this.height = height;
                return this;
            }

            public Builder bodyLength(String bodyLength) {
                this.bodyLength = bodyLength;
                return this;
            }

            public Builder species(String species) {
                this.species = species;
                return this;
            }

            public Builder acquisitionDate(String acquisitionDate) {
                this.acquisitionDate = acquisitionDate;
                return this;
            }

            public Builder acquisitionCountry(String acquisitionCountry) {
                this.acquisitionCountry = acquisitionCountry;
                return this;
            }

            public Builder inServiceCountry(String inServiceCountry) {
                this.inServiceCountry = inServiceCountry;
                return this;
            }

            public Builder trainingStatus(String trainingStatus) {
                this.trainingStatus = trainingStatus;
                return this;
            }

            public Builder reserved(boolean reserved) {
                this.reserved = reserved;
                return this;
            }

            public Monkey build() {
                return new Monkey(this);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Monkey{" +
                    "name='" + name + '\'' +
                    ", gender='" + gender + '\'' +
                    ", age='" + age + '\'' +
                    ", weight='" + weight + '\'' +
                    ", tailLength='" + tailLength + '\'' +
                    ", height='" + height + '\'' +
                    ", bodyLength='" + bodyLength + '\'' +
                    ", species='" + species + '\'' +
                    ", acquisitionDate='" + acquisitionDate + '\'' +
                    ", acquisitionCountry='" + acquisitionCountry + '\'' +
                    ", inServiceCountry='" + inServiceCountry + '\'' +
                    ", trainingStatus='" + trainingStatus + '\'' +
                    ", reserved=" + reserved +
                    '}';
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You should provide more explanation of the accessors, the _List_, and possibly just offer the _builder_ pattern.

Answer (score -2):

You're still missing an argument.

```
name                    "Steve"
gender                  "male"
age                     "24"
weight                  "15.4"
tailLength              "12"
height                  "20"
bodyLength              "16"
species                 "capuchin"
acquisitionDate         "04-26-1999"
aquisitionCountry       "United States"
reserved                "intake"
inServiceCountry        false
                        "United States"
```

Comment: An argument to what?

Comment: @PeterMortensen, of the _Monkey_ constructor method.  The first column here is the _constructor_, and the second one is the _call_.